# Why would the Russian army shoot fleeing civilians in Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

There have been several reports from Ukraine during the recent war, where a "humanitarian corridor" is supposedly set up so that civilians can leave their city under siege, but is not respected.

What reasons are their for either side of the war to not respect the designated corridors and cease fires?

Comment: Could you post the links to such reports? On the one hand, the war crimes are certainly happening; on the other hand, in the climate of the current ifnormation war one shouldn't trust everything one hears.

Comment: We cannot know what Putin is thinking. The title is not helpful. Try; what reasons could Putin have for ordering the targeting of civilians?

Comment: You could add a few possible items to your list; for example, using terror to force Ukraine to surrender. Weapons being so useless they land in the wrong place. Soldiers being undisciplined and firing randomly. Putin reacting with fury because the Ukrainians are making a mockery of his vaunted army. etcetera

Comment: Smells a bit of propaganda. Edit as suggested in comments.

Comment: You lack an option: To instill fear and to break Ukrainian morale. To make Selenskyy capitulate to stop the suffering. But the *reasons* the Russians have are all speculation, so I won't provide this as an answer. Suffice to say, if you think sinister enough, there is ample reason to target the population. Think of the allied firebombing of Dresden and other german cities in WWII.

Comment: I originally read something about this in national media in my mother tongue (which is overall reliable and independent). There's also some discussion about it in this UN report.
https://www.un.org/press/en/2022/sc14823.doc.htm , and some other English sources are these https://nypost.com/2022/03/07/russians-plant-landmines-in-ukraine-safe-corridor-report/ https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/3/8/ukraine-accuses-russia-shelling-mariupol-evacuation-corridor

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that my question seems to be taken as a pro-Russian stance, I believe any rational person will see Ukraine as the victim in this conflict. But sympathising with them does not mean one should not ask questions about Russian strategy

Comment: @Polygnome Dresden after WWII was probably also not logic from a strict military point of view, but a form of retaliation after Germans have been attacking the allies for long time. This kind of fits with the first suggestion: emotionally driven/hate

Comment: Targeting people who flee only instills fear in those who have already given up, so in a cost-benefit analysis of flee or fight it makes fight more attractive: they 'll target you anyway.

Comment: This will be very difficult next to impossible to answer with certainty. For example, probably nobody would like to admit that Civilians died because of stupidity or even hate, even if this was the case. Very likely Civilians died already because of these things in a war of this scale. I therefore think that the correctness of any answer cannot be verified and the question is unfortunately unanswerable.

Comment: I think this question is somewhat wrongly phrased or premised. I'm pretty sure the majority of civilian casualties are due to the fire direction doctrines of the Russian army, especially for indirect fire, rather than soldiers taking aim at civilians. See e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71506/interdiction-fire-in-urban-areas-status-under-international-law

Comment: ultimately, probably pretty much harassment ('harassment/harassing fire'), rather than anything of serious military value. If someone was called out on it they could simply say 'intelligence suggested combatants in the area'... (edit: Fizz has the same thoughts)

Comment: And sometimes civilians are in proximity of armed forces as in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XH34SIk6yIo) which makes them valid "incidental targets" (aka "collateral damage") alas.

Comment: @Wouter Dresden and Hiroshima are actually (the most well-known) examples of *strategic bombing* - the policy intended to incur suffering on the population, breaking the moral and inciting to surrender. It was considered acceptable then, and even 30 years later in Vietnam. However, by modern standards it would be a war crime.